# ESX SAN overbooked, what happens if storage limit reached?

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage, storage-area-network, vmware-esx, thin-provisioning

In ESX you can easily overbook the available storage with the Virtual Guests. What happens if a overbooked SAN reaches its capacity limit?

Its not an actual problem i'm faced with, we just had the discussion in the office and no one knows exactly what happens.

Comment: You're referring to "thin provisioning", right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By 'overbooked' do you mean overcommitted via the use of VMWare thinning? if so then what happens is that all reads stay good but any VMs that want to write can't - it's as simple as that, they get a SCSI 'block not available to be written to' error and have to deal with it however the OS/filesystem would do in that situation.

Comment: @ThomasSpycher This is incorrect. By "overbooked", I believe you are referring to "Thin Provisioned". [Thin Provisioned VMs will pause](http://www.vcritical.com/2009/10/easy-recovery-from-a-full-vmware-esx-datastore/) when they run out of datastore space.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't use it so was assuming it did what happens to physicals, good spot, I'll delete shortly.

Comment: Damn, can't delete an accepted answer :(

Answer (score 3):

Your VMs will pause and say that there's no free space on the volume which the virtual machine(s) reside on.

> When a datastore runs out of space, thin-provisioned virtual disks can
>   no longer dynamically grow to accommodate additional storage demand. 
>   When VMware ESX detects this condition, virtual machines in need of
>   additional storage are instantly paused to prevent guest operating
>   systems from failing.

With video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4G8MEC14eKU

Edit:

This just happened to a remote domain controller this morning.

> All services are down on node ewwhite - dc3.  New Outage records have
>   been created and service level availability calculations will be
>   impacted until this outage is resolved.

[image]

Comment: only if the virtual machine files are on the same storage as the vmdk

Comment: But when i pause the VM, its current memory needs to get written somewhere?

Comment: When I say "pause", I mean that VMware will stop the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the model of your storage array; generally the volume will go read-only or off-line, which will cause interesting problems to your VMs. Primarily shutdowns, in my experience.